# At American colleges, are student evaluations of teaching subject to code of conduct?

Tags: course-evaluation

It is well-known that student evaluations of teaching tend to be spiced with language that is insulting, sexually harassing, sexist, or racist.

Most American colleges have a code of conduct that is would disprove such remarks if they were face-to-face or anonymous writings on the wall.

Does that code of conduct apply to student evaluations of teaching at American colleges, or are they considered exceptions? These course evaluations are largely anonymous, which is why students feel enabled to engage in speech they usually wouldn't utter. But this occurs via university media, not somewhere out in the streets or the dark web.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I address a student systematically boosting their grades by filing frivolous complaints?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/148837/how-can-i-address-a-student-systematically-boosting-their-grades-by-filing-frivo)

Comment: No, not at all. That question is about a completely unrelated matter.

Comment: I suspect every college has its own policy, so we won't be able to give a general answer.

Comment: "It is well-known that student evaluations of teaching tend to be spiced with language that is insulting, sexually harassing, sexist, or racist." Strong introduction there, totally not leading the question. I am not sure where you are teaching but if that is your experience, damn....

Comment: A possible mitigation for this issue would be adding a profanity filter to the online feedback system.

Comment: Can you say how this is well-known?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are subject to the code of conduct.  However, they are usually anonymous, so there is no means of enforcement.

Comment: As far as I know, when those evaluations are submitted online, then there are records of who submitted them. Furthermore, if a University institution relays such comments, aren't they violating the code of conduct themselves?

Comment: @Ambicion so anonymous is not relevant - if you promise students the evaluations are anonymous should you keep your word?  Surely that comes under “ethical” or does that not count for you?

Comment: @SolarMike Veiled accusations are not called for.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist afaik these evalutaions are given by students as they are told that they are anonymous... is there a different meaning somewhere then?

Comment: @SolarMike: that counts as balancing competing values. While keep the promise of anonymity is a value, the ethics is not as clear cut.

Comment: @Ambicion so you make it clear to the students that the survey is no longer anonymous? If you don’t then that must be unethical.  Calling it a balance of values seems weasely words...

Comment: @SolarMike You said "Surely that comes under “ethical” or does that not count for you?"  This implies "I think you do not care about ethics." which is inappropriate.  Also, your suggested duplicate is inappropriate.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist the answers in that duplicate do discuss the code of conduct from a couple of directions.

Comment: @SolarMike Mark duplicates based on the question, not the answers.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist then read the answers - may be there is useful information...

Comment: Could we please move the discussion about the duplicate question to the comment thread where it belongs?